# Automatic updates not working/plugins not installing

Tags: plugins, updates

I am trying to run an automatic update from Wordpress 3.0 to 3.02.  However, I get the following error message:

"Unable to locate WordPress Root directory.

Installation Failed"

I also cannot install plugins on the same server.  The error message for the plugins is quite similar:
"Plugin could not be deleted due to an error: Unable to locate WordPress Plugin directory."

I have contacted the host but they have not been much help.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Jeff

Comment: Do you normally update via FTP, or should the server be able to write to the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff, unfortunately this looks like a problem with your hosting setup, so your host will be the only one who can help.  If they can't, and the problem doesn't correct itself, I'd recommend exporting your site and moving to a more supportive host.

In the meantime, though, who is your current host?  If you have FTP access, try manually updating a plug-in by transferring the new files to your server.  If that works, then you can manually update WordPress using the [standard upgrade instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress).

If you don't have FTP access and still can't auto-update, there's not much more we can do without going through your host directly.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I was afraid you might say that.  I do have ftp access and will try an update later, but my main concern is giving the client easy access to updating. I will contact the host again now. Thank you.