# automatic plugin install availability: server configuration

Tags: plugins, server, configuration

[This link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/automatic-updates-not-working-plugins-not-installing) shows how it may be possible that WordPress may not be able
to download and install a plugin via its web interface (known as
automatic plugin install). However it may be still be able to
upload a plugin via file transfer protocol and extract it.

On a Linux box, as a first step, I want to be able to check whether
the server is properly configured so as to allow for wordpress automatic installs
without and prior to actually downloading and installing wordpress.

Is this possible and what should I check for?

Thanks.